# Save return as <br>

Tags: php

I'm saving a textarea to a to a file using php and then want to then use in a 
include 'text.txt';. How can I have all the textarea's returns save as `<br>`?

Thanks for any help

Comment: the `nl2br()`-function should help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) does exactly that, so call it on the input before saving it.